# Control node position in ggalluvial

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my alluvial plot I would like to control the vertical position of the nodes. Specifically I'd like to align nodes of the same value (e.g., "Meet" in fall and "Meet" in spring), to avoid sloping alluvia like the blue example below where slope falsely indicates growth. If I could center the nodes of the same value on the same y-axis value I think I could minimize such false signals.

[image]

```
library(ggalluvial)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(57)

levels_score <- c("Below", "Meet")

ds_sankey <- 
  tibble(
    fall = c("Below", "Below", "Meet", "Meet"),
    spring = c("Below", "Meet", "Below", "Meet"),
    n = runif(n = 4, min = 100, max = 500)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    fall = factor(fall, levels = levels_score),
    spring = factor(spring, levels = levels_score),
    n = round(n)
  ) 

ds_sankey %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = n, axis1 = fct_rev(fall), axis2 = fct_rev(spring))) +
  geom_alluvium(width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/4, color = "grey") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("fall", "spring"), expand = c(.05, .05))
```

Comment: i don't see that the slope indicates growth... the value is represented by the width right?

Comment: @CalumYou the river width does represent the size of the group from the left that moved to the group on the right, but with ordered nodes a viewer might intuit that upward slopes signal growth and downward slopes signal decline.

Comment: I'm just confused about how you expect this to look - aligning the nodes would mean that you need to have gaps between the categories which makes the reading of the total observations much less readable. can you provide expected output, even with a sketch?

Comment: Total observations does not vary in my plot, so gaps between nodes is precisely what I am after.

Comment: @Joe that is not possible in **ggalluvial**. A lot of people like having spaces between what i call the "strata", and for that you can try the parallel set plots in **ggforce**; but you want something specific to repeated counts data (the same factor levels at each position in the diagram), which i've never seen a Sankey or alluvial diagram designed to do. (Though i'd be interested to see any examples.)

Comment: Just came across this note in the `ggalluvial` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html): "An important feature of these diagrams is the meaningfulness of the vertical axis: No gaps are inserted between the strata, so the total height of the diagram reflects the cumulative weight of the observations. "